# Azure Data Factory DataFlow exclude 1 column from expression columns()

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm looking for a solution for the following problem.
I've created the following expression in a Derived Column in Azure Data Factory DataFlow

md5(concatWS("||", toString(columns())))

But from the above expression column()  I want to extract 1 Column.

so something like this md5(concatWS("||", toString(columns()-'PrimaryKey'))). I cannot exclude the primary key column with a select in front of the derived because I need it in a later stage.
So in Databricks i'm executing the following, but I want to achieve this as well in ADF
non_key_columns = [column for column in dfsourcechanges.columns if column not in key_columns]

Are there any suggestions, how I can solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [byNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#bynames) function to do this. Create an array and add all your column names into it except 'PrimaryKey'. Then pass it to byNames function as first parameter. Something like this expression:`md5(concatWS("||", toString(byNames(['yourColumn1','yourColumn2',...]))))`

Comment: If I would like to dynamically compute which specific columns to hash, byNames not allowance. In other words, the array puts within byNames should be hard code